# How to remove 0 or more tokens (words), where they might come up sequentially or with data in between?

Tags: r, regex

How to extract only the country names from a variable such as the following.

```r
tibble::tribble(
    ~country, 
    '{"United States"}', 
    '{NULL}', 
    '{NULL,NULL}', 
    '{"United States",NULL,Netherlands}', 
    '{Germany}', 
    '{Canada}', 
    '{NULL,NULL}', 
    '{Chile,"United States"}', 
    '{NULL,NULL,NULL}', 
    '{NULL,China, NULL}', 
)
```

- `NULL` can come up sequentially or not and up to 15 time in a single observation.
- Countries with multiple words, such as "United States" come up quoted, otherwise they are all unquoted.

It is somewhat easy to do in multiple runs, such as removing all `NULL`s, then
removing the duplicated commas, and then the parenthesis, but I was aiming
for a more efficient way of achieving something towards the following:

```
tibble::tribble(
    ~country, 
    'United States', 
    NA, 
    NA, 
    'United States,Netherlands', 
    'Germany', 
    'Canada', 
    NA, 
    'Chile,United States', 
    NA, 
    'China', 
)
```

Comment: Your example code doesn't work. I'm guessing that's the reason for the downvotes.

Comment: indeed, thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit brute-force with `gsub`s, but it works.

```r
dat$out <- gsub("^,|,$", "",
                trimws(gsub('NULL,?|["{}]', '', dat$country)))
dat
# # A tibble: 10 x 2
#    country                                out                        
#    <chr>                                  <chr>                      
#  1 "{\"United States\"}"                  "United States"            
#  2 "{NULL}"                               ""                         
#  3 "{NULL,NULL}"                          ""                         
#  4 "{\"United States\",NULL,Netherlands}" "United States,Netherlands"
#  5 "{Germany}"                            "Germany"                  
#  6 "{Canada}"                             "Canada"                   
#  7 "{NULL,NULL}"                          ""                         
#  8 "{Chile,\"United States\"}"            "Chile,United States"      
#  9 "{NULL,NULL,NULL}"                     ""                         
# 10 "{NULL,China, NULL}"                   "China"
```

From here, you can replace the empty strings with `""` with

```r
dat$out[!nzchar(dat$out)] <- NA
```